# A Single wireless network is not showing up in Ubuntu that used too, and other devices have no issue finding or connecting to it

Tags: 11.04, networking, wireless, samsung

Up until about a week ago I could connect to my wireless, but now I suddenly can't. Every other wireless in the area show up in the network manager. My kindle can connect to it, my friend can connect to it (in windows) without having connected to it before. My other netbook (Samsung NC10) can connect to it, but my other Samsung N150 now cannot even see it.

- I have tried deleting the old auto entry for it in the network manager
- Tried disabling and enabling both the networking and the wireless through the network indicator.
- Disabled the networking through the hardware shortkut key thing [fn] + [F9]
- Attempting to connect to it as if it was a hidden network.

I'm at a loss, how would I go about debugging and unborking my computer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problems a few weeks ago in a friends house. The problem was that the router was using channel 13 and by default the drivers didn't allow this. I make him change the channel and it started working again. But i think there is a way to allow this channels in the driver.

Comment: Ah! `iwlist channel` tells me that the computer only does 1-11 and my other netbook tells me it's on channel 13. Finally makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I spend a while googling before finding why only one network didn't showed up.

Comment: Blown away at the fact that it's 2020 and this solved my problem after too many hours. Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install on an older Samsung laptop. I had changed the router channel to try speed up the wifi a while back. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 12.04, list of networks but my home network is not on it.

Click **Network Manager** → **Edit Connections** → **Wireless** → **Delete the 'home network'** → **Close** and reboot.

Then go back to **Network Manager** → **Edit Connections** → **Create New Wireless Network** → **Enter Info** → **Save**. Reboot. All is fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to solve this problem on and off for AN ENTIRE YEAR (OK, we have a small baby/toddler, and as of two weeks ago, another one, so I haven't been able to give it my full attention - but even so!)

And here's the solution!  Log into the Router.  Change the Channel from 13 to Channel 5, and hey presto!  It works.  All the messing around with WPA Supplicant, drivers etc. was irrelevant.

Don't need to do anything on your computer.  Just change router settings.

Damm I feel stupid now.

(To be very clear, the problem I was having wasn't that WiFi didn't work - It was that WiFi clearly DID work, but I couldn't see MY router, just every other router in the building)

Comment: The general suggestion in this answer is to cycle through the channels available on the router. There are situations that may cause it to change the channel it broadcasts on which in turn might cause connection issues for lan machines.

Answer (score 1):

If the network isn't showing up, you still can connect to it by

1. Clicking at the network icon and
2. Choosing "Connect to Hidden Wireless Network" > "New"
3. Then put the name and password.
   (This works even if it isn't a hidden network)

[image]

[image]

Comment: That sadly doesn't work for me. The network is very much being broadcast too as other devices are picking it up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue where my phone was connecting to the wireless at the coffee shop while my laptop wasn't even seeing the network.

The issue was that the wireless network was 5GHz only and my laptop wireless card was 2.4 GHz only.

I discovered the wireless network was 5GHz only by using an app on my phone to scan the wireless space.

You can see what frequencies are supported by your wireless card with `iwlist freq` which will give you a quick listing of supported frequencies or `iw phy` which will tell you more than you ever wanted to know about your wireless card.

A Google search on my wireless card model confirmed that it was not a dual band card.